# Apply a rule based on row values of a dataset

Tags: r, traminer

I'm a starter in R, I already developed some programs, but the issue that I will expose you never happened to me yet. Here is the TSE dataframe I'm dealing with :

```
   ID TIME EVENT
1 150    1     A
2 150    2     B
3 150    2     C
4 150    2     D
5 151    1     C
6 151    2     A
7 151    3     B
8 151    3     D
```

This dataframe contains 3 variables :

ID   : Id of the person,

TIME : Time index,

EVENT: An event that occurs at a certain moment of time.

I want to drop row(s) for which two or more events occur **at the same time value (TIME)**  based on a rule. Let's suppose the rule is : C>B>A>D (where ">" means preferable)

So, in my example, I would like to keep only these rows :

```
   ID TIME EVENT
1 150    1     A
3 150    2     C
5 151    1     C
6 151    2     A
7 151    3     B
```

You can easily see that rows 2,4,8 vanished because of the defined rule

I guess this shouldn't be so tricky to program but I really have no clue on how to put it down.

Thanks you all in anticipation.

Jérémie P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using `dplyr`.

First reproduce your data

```
DF <- data.frame(ID = rep(150:151, each=4), 
                 time=c(1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3), 
                 EVENT=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "C", "A", "B", "D"))

target_rule <- c("C", "B", "A", "D")
```

Then we can use a combination of commands from `dplyr` to order, select, etc. 
Below I use a factor version of your `EVENT` to sort them according to your taget rule.

```
library("dplyr")
DF %>% 
  group_by(ID, time) %>%                               # Consider each combo of ID and time    
  mutate(fevent=factor(EVENT, levels=target_rule)) %>% # Create ordered version of EVENT 
  arrange(fevent) %>%                                  # Sort according to rule
  summarise(EVENT=first(EVENT)) %>%                    # Pick just the first 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(ID)
```

This produces

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
     ID  time EVENT fevent    rn
  <int> <dbl> <fct> <fct>  <int>
1   150     1 A     A          1
2   150     2 C     C          1
3   151     1 C     C          1
4   151     2 A     A          1
5   151     3 B     B          1
```

Comment: Nice solution, but instead of explicitly adding row numbers and keeping the first row, couldn't you use `summary(Event = first(EVENT)` to get the first element of your groups only?

Comment: @ArthurSpoon Yeah you are right. Much cleaner. Have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot it really helps me